# Change top attribute while using an animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, I've created a button to collapse the navbar (literally just the .collapsed div) except when I try to move it with the navbar, nothing happens. I've tried using some DOM with timeout function (to match with the animation timing), used class combination properties (in CSS), adding classes manually using JS (properties contained within class), etc. I'm not really sure what's up with my code, but I much appreciate it if you could take a look. Currently I'm trying a DOM JS method, just FYI.

Thanks!

```css
 body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #464c53;
      color: white;
  }

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #343C46;
  }
  
  .navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 39px;

    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  .navbar a.active {
    background-color: #04aa6d;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    /* transition: height 0.25s; */
  }
  
  .yHover a, .dropdown .dropbtn{
    transition: background-color 0.15s ease-out;
  }
  .yHover a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease-out;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.699);
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu {
    /* ---Check jQuery--- */
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    left:100%;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  

  .collapse {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #343C46;
    color: #fffefed7;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 5.5rem #525c5c, 0em 0em 0.9em #ffffff6b;
    cursor: pointer; 
    top: 4.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: rgba(32, 30, 30, 0.863);
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;  
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    right: 50%;
    background: radial-gradient( var(--myColor2), var(--myColor1));

    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out 1ms,  --myColor1 0.2s, --myColor2 0.2s ease-out 1ms, color 0.2s ease-in-out 1ms;
  }


  .collapse:hover {  
    --myColor1: gold;
    --myColor2: rgb(248, 248, 115);
    color: black;
    }


  @property --myColor1 {
    syntax: '<color>';
    initial-value: #343C46;
    inherits: false;
  }
  
  @property --myColor2 {
    syntax: '<color>';
    initial-value: #343C46;
    inherits: false;
  }

  .collapse:active {  
    transform: translateY(1px);
    background-color: rgb(109, 103, 103);
  }

  .collapse.sticky {
    top: 4.5%;
  }

  .repos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
  }

  .sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  
  .dhq {
    display: flexbox; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 3.5%; 
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fadingElems {
    animation: fadeIn 1.5s ease-in;
  }
  
  
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "cssjavascript/style.css"/>
    <script src="cssjavascript/addon.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
  
   <style>



        h3 {
             left: 2%;
             max-width: 200px;
             padding: 20px;
             margin: 20px;
        }  

        p {
            max-width: 200px;
             padding: 20px;
             margin: 20px;
             word-wrap: break-word;  
        }

        
        
        .faded h1{
          position: absolute; 
          z-index: 3;
          text-align: center; 
          position: relative; 
          text-shadow: rgba(10, 9, 4, 0.616) 1px 0 20px; 
          background-color: rgb(31, 30, 30);

          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFD700, #F3F389);
          -webkit-background-clip: text;
          -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

        }
        
        .faded h2 {
          text-shadow: rgb(204, 203, 197) 1px 0 20px; 
          font-size: 32px;
          position: relative; 
          z-index: 3;
          text-align: center;    
        }

        .fadeAn1 {
          animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in;
        }

        .fadeAn2 {
          animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in;
        }

        .navbar.draggedUp {
          animation: dragUp 0.5s ease-in 0.5ms;
        }

        .navbar.draggedDown {
          animation: dragDown 0.25s ease-out;

        }

        .collapse.rotatedUp {
          animation: rotateUp 2s;
        }

        .collapse.rotatedDown {
          animation: rotateDown 2s;
        }

        @keyframes dragUp {
          0% {transform: translateY(0%); top: 0%;}
          100% {transform: translateY(-100%); top: -100%;}
        }

        @keyframes dragDown {
          0% {transform: translateY(-100%);}
          100% {transform: translateY(0%);}
        }

        @keyframes rotateUp {
          to { 
             -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
              transform: rotate(180deg);
             }
          }

        @keyframes rotateDown{
          to {
          -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
           transform: rotate(-180deg);
           };
        }
      
    
    </style>
    <title>Landing Page</title>
 </head>

 <body>

<div class = "fadingElems">
  <div class="navbar" id = "navbar1">
    <div class = "hidden">
    <div class = "yHover">
    <a href="#news">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#">Jobs/Opportunities</a>
    <a href="#">Learn</a>

    <div class="dropdown">

      <button class="dropbtn">Coding &#9660;
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a class = "parentdrop" href="#">Web Development &#9654;</a> 
      <div class = "dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">HTML</a>
        <a href="#">CSS</a>
        <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
      </div>
      <a class = "parentdrop" href="#">Areas of Development &#9654;</a> 
      <div class = "dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#">Front End</a>
          <a href="#">Back End</a>
          <a href="#">Full Stack</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">News</a>
      </div>
      
    </div> 
    <a href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a>

   

      </div>
  
        
      </div>
      <div class = "dhq">
        <a href = "./landpage.html"><img src = "./images/dhq.png" title = "Developer HQ Home"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
          <button title = "Collapse Navbar" onclick = "toggleFunction();" class = "collapse" id = "collapseB"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            expand_less
            </span></button>
   </div>

      




      <img src = "./images/dhq_home.png" style = "display: block; width: 100%; height: auto;" title = "Developer HQ: Where future developers learn." >

      <div class = "faded">
        <h1 class = "faded1" style = "text-align: center;">Developer HQ</h1>
        <h2 class = "faded2" style = "text-align: center;">Where future developers learn.</h2>
      </div>

   </div>

   <script>
      window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

      var navbar1 = document.getElementById("navbar1");
      let collapseButton = document.getElementById("collapseB");

      let sticky = navbar1.offsetTop;

      function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
          navbar1.classList.add("sticky");
          collapseButton.classList.add("sticky");
          collapseButton.style.width = "25px";
          collapseButton.style.height = "25px";

        } else {
          navbar1.classList.remove("sticky");
          collapseButton.classList.remove("sticky");
          collapseButton.style.width = "25px";
          collapseButton.style.height = "25px";
          collapseButton.style.top = "10vh";
        }
      }
   </script>

    <script>
      let toggle = true;
      const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
      const collapsed = document.querySelector('.collapsed');

   
      function toggleFunction(){
        toggle ? collapseNav() : openNav();
        toggle = !toggle;
      }

      function collapseNav() {
        
        navbar.classList.add('draggedUp');
        navbar.classList.remove('draggedDown');

        // The class I'm adding to handle its reposition
        collapsed.classList.add("repos");


  

        setTimeout(() => {          
           $(".navbar").hide();
           $(".collapse").show();
      }, 500);
   
      }
          
      function openNav() {
        navbar.classList.remove('draggedUp');
        navbar.classList.add('draggedDown');

        // The class I'm adding to handle its reposition
        collapsed.classList.remove("repos");



        //  collapsed.classList.add("rotatedDown");
        //  collapsed.classList.remove("rotatedUp");

        setTimeout(() => {          
          $(".navbar").show();
        }, 500);

   
      }
    </script>

    <script>
   $(function() {
  $('.parentdrop').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      const $submenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-submenu');
      $submenu.show();
    },
    mouseleave: function (event) {
      const $submenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-submenu');
      $submenu.hide();
    }
  });
  
  $('.dropdown-submenu').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $(this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.parentdrop').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      const $submenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-submenu');
      $submenu.show();
    },
    mouseleave: function (event) {
      const $submenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-submenu');
      $submenu.hide();
    }
  });
  
  $('.dropdown-submenu').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $(this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});

  
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const faded_h1 = entry.target.querySelector('.faded1');
    const faded_h2 = entry.target.querySelector('.faded2');

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      faded_h1.classList.add('fadeAn1');
      faded_h2.classList.add('fadeAn2');

      return; // if we added the class, exit the function
    }

    // We're not intersecting, so remove the class!
    faded_h1.classList.remove('fadeAn1');
    faded_h2.classList.remove('fadeAn2');
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.faded'));

      </script>
      
      



 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet errors because there is no element with class `collapsed`.

Comment: Also if you don't mind, can you answer the question? I wouldn't want to answer it myself because I feel like I would steal all the credit from you, and plus you would earn free rep. Thanks again!

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: YES LOL I'M SO SORRY